# Collections.copy problem

Tags: java, collections

I want that `b1` and `b2` to have their own sets of elements, then b1 and b2 should have its own elements in memory so that when b1/b2 is modified, others should not be affected.

`buffer` is an `ArrayList` containing many elements

```
List<Integer>  b1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(buffer.size()) ;
List<Integer>  b2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(buffer.size()) ) ;
Collections.copy(b1, buffer);
Collections.copy(b2, buffer);
```

I am getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Source does not fit in dest
    at java.util.Collections.copy(Collections.java:531)
    at Trees.containsSumPrint(Trees.java:243)
    at Trees.main(Trees.java:125)
```

Answer (score 10):

The `ArrayList(int)` constructor gives a `List` that has size 0 it only ensures that `n` elements can be added before it needs to reallocate the underlying array.

A better way you can copy the lists is:

```
b1.addAll(buffer);
b2.addAll(buffer);
```

The semantics are the same as when you would have first added `buffer.size()` nulls to each array and called `Collections.copy(b1,buffer);`

---

If you want a deep copy (the elements also copied) you are going to have to handle each element separately

```
for(MyObject obj:buffer){
    b1.add(obj.clone());
    b2.add(obj.clone());
}
```

Comment: after  we do b1.addALL(buffer) will both buffer and b1 have its own seperate copy of elemets?will modifying one affect other?

Comment: each will have it's own collection that you can modify separately. But calling b1.get(0).doSomething() will also affect b2.get(0) (they remain the same objects) but Integers like in the question are immutable so you can get away with them sharing the objects

Answer (score 1):

The `Collections.copy(...)` [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) says this:

> *"Copies all of the elements from one list into another. After the operation, the index of each copied element in the destination list will be identical to its index in the source list. **The destination list must be at least as long as the source list.** If it is longer, the remaining elements in the destination list are unaffected."*.

The `ArrayList(int)` constructor creates an empty list whose *capacity* (not size!) is given by the argument.

Since `b1` is initially empty, copying a non-empty list to it (using `copy`) will fail, since the precondition (in bold) does not hold true (in general).

Basically, `Collections.copy(...)` is the wrong method to use.

What you should really be doing is this:

```
List<Integer> b1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(buffer.size());
List<Integer> b2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(buffer.size());
b1.addAll(buffer);
b2.addAll(buffer);
```

---

I'm assuming that you don't *really* want to create new instances of the list elements.  If you do, I should point out that creating new instances of `Integer` objects is waste of time since `Integer` (like the other wrapper classes and `String`) is an immutable class.

Comment: That won't create two lists of distinct (copied) objects, which is what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

You want a deep copy of each element. There is no standard way to achieve this, because deep copying could involve copying nested references to (collections of) other objects. The best way to do this is create a copy constructor, java.lang.Integer happens to have one! So I think you should do something like:

```
List<Integer> buffer = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 });
List<Integer> b1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> b2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (Integer element : buffer) {
    b1.add(new Integer(element));
    b2.add(new Integer(element));
}
```

This actually creates TWO copies, one in each target list. If one of the lists may contain the original elements just do:

```
for (Integer element : buffer) {
    b1.add(new Integer(element));
    b2.add(element);
}
```

Note that there also exists the cloneable interface. I advise against using this because it is easy to make mistakes with referred classes, collections and subclassing. A copy constructor is much easier to get right. See [this page](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71) for some corroboration.

EDIT: on re-reading, maybe you don't want deep copies, in which case you can use the 'addAll' method as described by others. This will allow you to create multiple collections of the same object instances. You can then modify the contents/order of objects in one collection without affecting other collections. However if you modify an object instance, this will obviously be reflected by all other collections as well.

Also, StephenC rightfully points out that my above example is nutty. I agree, one would never 'deep copy' Integers like that normally, but it would makes sense for custom objects containing collections/references which I thought was the issue here.

Comment: This is nutty.  Unless the OP is doing something weird, creating new `Integer` objects is a waste of time ... even if you think that's what he asked for.

Comment: @StephenC: Agreed. I am assuming OP used Integers as an example here, and really wants to do this for objects of arbitrary complexity.